# CodeIgniter Twig - Validation Errors

Tags: php, codeigniter, twig

I have a bit of problem with Twig in CodeIgniter.

I have tried to integrate Twig in CodeIgniter, so I would have clean templates.

[CodeIgniter Simple and Secure Twig](https://github.com/kenjis/codeigniter-ss-twig)

This is really good, it is my first time to use templating engine.

But I encountered a problem. My form validation messages won't show if I submit the form.

```html
  public function user_register()
  {
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'trim|required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'trim|required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'trim|required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('firstname', 'Firstname', 'trim|required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('lastname', 'Lastname', 'trim|required');

    if ($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE) {
      $data = [
        'title' => 'Register',
      ];

      $this->twig->display('user_register', $data);
    }

  }
```

If I do:

```
<?php echo validation_errors(); ?>
```

It won't output anything. My observation is, now that I have used Twig for my views, I cannot use php tags. Is it right to assume that?

If yes, how can I  output validation errors in CodeIgniter using Twig?

I would appreciate any suggestions, and links that you will post. Hope you can guide me or lead me where to look at.

Thankyou.

**Edit**

I have tried using `{{ validation_errors() }}`

But it gives me an error: Please see screenshot:

[image: Error message {{ validation_errors() }}]

Comment: Have you tried to print your variable's value using {{ validation_errors() 
 }}

Comment: @Jobayerm Hi! Yes I have tried that. But it shows an error. I will edit my question to include the screen shot of the error. Thanks

Comment: Hi @danangeloalcanar, can you try with if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) { double equal instead of triple equal

Answer (score 2):

You can do it using a very simple process like below code - 
1. write this code in your controller

```
$data['errors'] = validation_errors();
$this->twig->display('user_register', $data);
```

2. 
then inside your view, write `{{ $errors }}`

I have tested it & it's working without any problem.

Comment: Thankyou for helping me. You answer also works. I found the answer by editing the library. Again, thank you. :)

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the answer. In the package I included in my question, I just edited the file *application/libraries/Twig.php*:

```
  private $functions_safe = [
    'form_open',
    'form_close',
    'form_error',
    'set_value',
    'form_hidden',
    'validation_errors', /** I just add this line and validation errors worked perfectly */
    'form_input',
    'form_password',
  ];
```

For anyone who will use the package above, hope this helps. Just add the function that you want to use in your view in the `$functions_safe` array.

Thanks!